# How do you correctly push into Empty Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hey I am creating a simple Star Wars quiz and could use some help. Thank you!

JS(Idea here is to get values to later push into array)

```
function addValues() {
  let value1 = document.getElementById('Q1').value;
  let value2 = document.getElementById('Q2').value;
  let value3 = document.getElementById('Q3').value;

  answerChoices.push(value1);
  answerChoices.push(value2);
  answerChoices.push(value3);

  console.log(value1);
}
```

HTML (Added Html to replace index when start button is clicked)

```
<p id='timer'>Timer</p>
<div id='questions'>

  <h3>Where did Luke Skywalker Grow Up?</h3>
  <form id="Q1">
    <input type="radio" name="birthPlanet" id="Hoth" value="Hoth" /><label>Hoth</label>
    <input type="radio" name="birthPlanet" id="Tatooine" value="Tatooine" /><label>Tatooine</label>
    <input type="radio" name="birthPlanet" id="Endor" value="Endor" /><label>Endor</label>
  </form>

  <h3>What planet did the Death Star blow up?</h3>
  <form id="Q2">
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" id="Q2" value="Exogal" /><label>Exogal</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" id="Q2" value="Yavin 4" /><label>Yavin 4</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" id="Q2" value="Aldreaan" /><label>Aldreaan</label>
  </form>

  <h3>What year did Star War first come out?</h3>
  <form id="Q3">
    <input type="text" name="Q3" id="Q3" /><label>Enter Text Here</label>
  </form> <br />
  <button onclick="endButton()">Finish Quiz</button>
</div>
```

ARRAY 
`let answerChoices= [];`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: Where is answerChoices declared and defined in your file in respect to the method?

Comment: its unclear what you want to achieve.Will you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Use a single form, and remove all `id` attributes from your inputs. To get values, grab the form element, then append the name: first `const f = document.getElementById('questionform');` then `f.birthPlanet` and so on to get the values.

Comment: In your HTML, the `Q1`, `Q2` and `Q3` elements are `<form>`s, and you can't read "the value" from a `<form>`. Only the input elements **inside** a form have values; not the form itself.  Furthermore, you repeat the id Q2 for both the **form and its child elements**, but using an id more than once on a page is *illegal* according to HTML specs.

Comment: Here's fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fzwokL7s/

Comment: Sorry, issues is that the array is empty when I try and push the values from the form into the array. When I call the array nothing is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is what you want .. try snippet

```js
function addValues(){
 let value1 = document.querySelector('input[name="Q1"]:checked');
    let value2 = document.querySelector('input[name="Q2"]:checked');
    let value3 = document.querySelector('input[name="Q3"]');

   let answerChoices = {
      'Q1' : value1.value,
        'Q2' : value2.value,
        'Q3' : value3.value
    
   }
    // console the hole values
    console.log(answerChoices);
    
    // console single value
    console.log(answerChoices.Q1);
}
```

```html
 <p id= 'timer'>Timer</p>
  <div id='questions'>

          <h3>Where did Luke Skywalker Grow Up?</h3>
          <form id="Q1">
              <input type="radio" name="Q1"  id="Hoth" value="Hoth" /><label>Hoth</label>
              <input type="radio" name="Q1"  id="Tatooine" value="Tatooine" /><label>Tatooine</label>
              <input type="radio" name="Q1"  id="Endor" value="Endor" /><label>Endor</label>
          </form>

          <h3>What planet did the Death Star blow up?</h3>
          <form id="Q2">
              <input type="radio" name="Q2"  id="Q2" value="Exogal" /><label>Exogal</label>
              <input type="radio" name="Q2"  id="Q2" value="Yavin 4" /><label>Yavin 4</label>
              <input type="radio" name="Q2"  id="Q2" value="Aldreaan" /><label>Aldreaan</label>
          </form>

          <h3>What year did Star War first come out?</h3>
          <form id="Q3">
              <input type="text" name="Q3" id="Q3" /><label>Enter Text Here</label>
          </form>  <br/>
    <button onclick="addValues()">Finish Quiz</button>
  </div>
```